# LAStools in QGIS error at activation: "wrong value for parameter 'OTB applications folder'..."

Tags: qgis, installation, lidar, lastools

I have a problem with LAStools in QGIS 2.14. I've followed the LAStools instructions for downloading LAStools for QGIS. `

I replaced
'lidar' folder in C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\lidar with the folder downloaded from http://rapidlasso.com.

I downloaded the 'LAStools' folder and put it in the following location: 'C:\LAStools'. I activate LAStools in to Processing, and type 'C:\LAStools' for the 'LAStools folder location', but I get the following message:

> "Wrong value for parameter "OTB applications folder":
>   Specified path does not exist:
>   C:/OSGEO4~1/apps\orfeotoolbox\applications"

LAStools appears in the processing toolbox. I can start to run a lasview. The data appears in 'just a little LAS and LAZ viewer', but the program hangs and then crashes.

Is this happening because of the error message? I have looked through the StackExchange for other examples of this specific problem, with no success. Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks Andre Silva. I'm afraid that post does not address my problem. In that case user33103 could not open the LAStools plugin or enable the toolbox. I can do both. In my case, I get an error message when I follow instructions to enable LAStools in the toolbox, and Lasview just seems to hang and crash. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version of QGIS 2.14 there should be no need to replace the 'lidar' folder in C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\lidar with the folder downloaded from http://rapidlasso.com/LAStools. This was only needed in earlier versions up to QGIS 2.8. For newer versions just do step 4 and then continue with step 6 of the install instructions from this [older blog article](http://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/).